# Passing multiple arguments to a block

Tags: ruby

I'm reading through 'the ruby programming language' and have come across the following piece of code.

```
a.inject do | sum, x |
    sum + x
end
```

I understand that x contains one element from a that will be passed to the bock but the 'sum' part is confusing me, is it some kind of operator or function or is it just another variable like x. I understand that the x variable could be called f, or v but if thats the case how does ruby know that x is that variable to pass the element to the iterator in, surly it could just as easily pass the variable into sum (if it is even a variable).

I hope that makes sense, as always I'm finding it had to put my confusion into works as if I understood the nature of the problem better I would be more likley to be able to find my own solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sum is the accumulator object, for example the following code:

```
(1..10).inject(0) do |sum, num| #sum is initialized to 0 and passed in as the accumulator
    sum + num #since sum is the accumulator, the result of this addition is stored in sum
end
```

The above code is the same as:

```
sum = 0
(1..10).each do 
    |num|
    sum = sum + num
end
```

You can give the accumulator object any valid variable name, of course better with a meaningful name in the context.

Comment: so in my example how does ruby know to give x the value, is it because its last in the list, or is it because sum is some kind of keyword? would `| x, sum |` do the same?

Comment: ok so (just to get it straight in my small brain), if i were to do this `| a, b, c, val |` then a, b and c would be variables that i coud use in the blocks and val because it was named last would be where the iterator passes a different value to each block

Comment: aaah, great, so the iterator defines the variables it expects, that clears everything up! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`sum` is just a name of a parameter - there's absolutely no magic in it. You may choose any name for it, for example:

```
a.inject do | accumulator, el |
    accumulator + el
end
```

Would do the same thing.

`inject` simply iterates through elements of `accumulator` and executes given block for each element of `a`. The important thing here, is that result of every iteration, becomes accessible for the next iteration as `accumulator`. Result of the last iteration becomes result of the whole `inject` invocation.